# How to not send a response body

Tags: php, restler

I'm trying to send a header response back from our api with a http status code 201 Created and a Location:header.

No matter what I do I get a response body too, something that I don't want.

If I return an empty string (return "";), restler will put the string '""' in the response body. If I return null or do not return anything at all restler will put the string 'null' in the response body.

How do I tell Restler to *not* send anything but headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE :-**

With the latest release of Restler 3 RC4. Returning null sends empty body for the response

This behaviour can be changed by setting

```
Defaults::$emptyBodyForNullResponse = false;
```

You can use `@status` comment to set the response code to 201

and @header comment for setting the location header

For older versions use the technique described below

---

From your api method, set both status and location header using header function followed by die or exit

```
header("HTTP/1.0 201 Created");
header('Location: http://api.example.com/item/45');
die();
```

This is a very valid use case that demands better way of doing this, We will soon update this answer with those solutions

Thanks for contributing to Restler :)